# LINQ vs foreach when trying to sum

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

Asymptotically optimal both would required O(n) (and, of course, n equals the length of the list) time to complete but in the first example the list would be iterated just once, while in the second one it would be iterated 5 times.

First way:

```
       foreach (var item in model)
       {
           fieldsSum.EnergyObjectCount += item.EnergyObjectCount;
           fieldsSum.HourlyCapacityUtilization += item.HourlyCapacityUtilization;
           fieldsSum.InstalledPower += item.InstalledPower;
           fieldsSum.NumberOfGuarantees += item.NumberOfGuarantees;
           fieldsSum.ProducedEnergy += item.ProducedEnergy;
       }
```

Second way:

```
       fieldsSum.EnergyObjectCount = model.Sum(item => item.EnergyObjectCount);
       fieldsSum.HourlyCapacityUtilization = model.Sum(item => item.HourlyCapacityUtilization);
       fieldsSum.InstalledPower = model.Sum(item => item.InstalledPower);
       fieldsSum.NumberOfGuarantees = model.Sum(item => item.NumberOfGuarantees);
       fieldsSum.ProducedEnergy = model.Sum(item => item.ProducedEnergy);
```

1) Is it considered a 'bad' practise to use the second way?

2) Does the compiler do any optimizations while building the .exe?

Comment: I consider the second one bad practice because your iterating over the same model 5 times

Comment: the question may be naive but it's still a valid question. why the -1? +1 from me

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Is it considered a 'bad' practise to use the second way?

Yes, why would you iterate over a list for five times while you can achieve the same thing with one iteration?

> 2) Does the compiler do any optimizations while building the .exe?

No because there is nothing to optimize here (for the compiler). At least I can't see any.

Comment: Iterating over a collection 5 times and doing 1/5th the work is not much more expensive than doing 5 times more work per iteration and doing 1 iteration.  That is, so long as the object being iterated isn't an unmaterialized database query, something that causes side effects, etc.

Comment: That's an example of an object being iterated deferring execution, that being the main case that results in a meaningful difference here.  When the object being enumerated isn't deferring execution, that doesn't happen.  Throw a `ToList` on the query and you'll see comparable times.  That's not to mention the benchmarking flaws such as not warming up the code, only doing the operation being tested once, etc.